# Panel в WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма, на эту форму я накладываю Panel1 (по размеру чуть меньше, чем сама форма), и Panel2 такую же как и Panel1. На самой форме, у меня уже были элементы, но после наложения "панелей", в конструкторе, я уже не могу увидеть, что у меня на этой форме. Можно ли как-то скрывать эти панели в конструкторе? или есть еще какие способы посмотреть что на этой форме?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На тулбаре Layout есть кнопки Bring to Front, Send to Back. Также эти команды доступны из контекстного меню контролов.
Выбрав пункт Send to Back, вы можете верхнюю на данный момент Панель переместить вниз, и станет видна другая.

Но это работает, если у обеих панелей непосредственным родителем является форма. А если вы мышкой перетащили одну панель в другую, то именно она станет родителем для первой.

Answer (score 2):

В окне свойства, сверху есть комбобокс со всеми контролами на форме. Там можно выбрать любой контрол, видимый или не видимый.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]